# How to check if column value exists? If exists update values in other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

HTML

```
<form action="../php/get_uploaded_wall.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="desktop_dimension_id">Desktop dimensions:</label>
            <span class="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkbox_value">
                        <input id="dc1280_800" type="checkbox" name="1280x800"> 1280x800</span>
                        <input id="db1280_800" class="desktop_disabled" type="file" name="desktop_path_1280x800" size="100" />
                    <span class="checkbox_value">
                        <input id="dc1366_768" type="checkbox" name="1366x768"> 1366x768</span>
                        <input id="db1366_768" class="desktop_disabled" type="file" name="desktop_path_1366x768" size="100" />
            </span>
```

PHP

```
$connectDB = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASENAME); 

//rename desktop walls & take out empty paths
        if(!empty($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['name'])){
            file_exists($desktop_filename_1280x800 = strtolower($desktop_dir_1280x800 . 'wall_desktop_1280x800_' .
                                   $_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1280x800]['name']));
        }   
        if(!empty($_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1366x768]['name'])){
            file_exists($desktop_filename_1366x768 = strtolower($desktop_dir_1366x768 . 'wall_desktop_1366x768_' .
                                   $_FILES[$desktop_fieldname_1366x768]['name']));
        }
```

SQL

```
//insert into SQL code here
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO walls(d_1280x800_path, d_1366x768_path) VALUES( '{$desktop_filename_1280x800}', '{$desktop_filename_1366x768}');";

//insert into database
    mysqli_query($connectDB, $insert_sql);
```

TABLES

Below is my `d_dimensions` table.

```
d_dimension_id    d_dimensions
1                 1280x800
2                 1366x768
```

and my `desktop_sizes` table.

```
wall_id (P,F)    d_dimension_id (P,F)
```

What I would like to do is check if certain path/wallpapaper is uploaded in my walls (not illustrated) table. So if the column `d_1280x800_path` contains a path I would like to store it in my `desktop_sizes` table. For example `wall_id` is `21` and the `d_dimension_id` for `1280x800` is `1`, `desktop_sizes` table would become:

```
wall_id (P,F)    d_dimension_id (P,F)
    21               1
```

another, if the same wallpaper with `wall_id=21` has `1366x768` size my `desktop_sizes` table would be:

```
wall_id (P,F)    d_dimension_id (P,F)
    21               1
    21               2
```

As a summary, I want to update table if another table's column contains some value. In my case update desktop_sizes table based on the values in walls and d_dimensions table. Am I able to explain clearly? How will I be able to do that with the code and tables given above?

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Comment: @tadman oh thanks! will take note of that.